# Find ng repeat end for the second time - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I can find the ng-repeat directive using the following code.

```
.directive('findNgRepeatEnd', [function () {
      return {
          scope: true,
          link: function (scope, element, attrs)                        
              if (scope.$last) {
                  debugger                           
              }
          }
      };
}])
```

**I have seen strange issue from the directive. When i add data, i can trace the last one. But when I remove the directive is not called.**

https://plnkr.co/edit/9gIFMkuWmXjIb9Xdhl58?p=preview

Comment: Can you make plunker please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your directive, the link only gets called once. You'll have to setup a watch:

```
.directive('findNgRepeatEnd', [function () {
      return {
          scope: true,
          link: function (scope, element, attrs)
              scope.$watch("$last", function(newVal) {
                  if (newVal) {
                      console.log("This element is the $last!");
                  }
              }                      
          }
      };
}])
```

Comment: Can't we do this without watch?

Comment: But if you see my plunker, the link called again when we add new item to the collection. This is not working only if we remove an item.

Comment: If we do more code, then the scope variable gets override. Can't we have this $last in the object?

Answer (score -1):

You should not write the $last logic in link method.

Here is an Edit:

```
.directive('findNgRepeatEnd', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
   if (scope.$last){
     window.alert("im the last!");
   }
  };
})
```

See full example here: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SLdAoYEVzQlh3BTT4yKu?p=preview)

Comment: Please check again, there is a change.